# Balanceo de carga sobre puentes wifi

Tags: redes

tengo una red local (192.168.0.0/24) de la que forman parte dos edificios conectados por medio de un par de antenas wifi de 5ghz que actúan de puente (bridged). En el edificio 1 tengo un servidor de archivos con conexión gigabit y las antenas son `ubiquiti` m5 5ghz con conexión a 100mbps.

Algo así:

```
               |-----antena )))(((( antena-----|
  switch GbE Edificio1                      switch FE Edificio2
     |         |-----antena )))(((( antena-----|       |
  Servidor                                           PC's
```

Mi consulta es la siguiente: ¿Existe alguna manera de implementar algún tipo de balanceo de carga si pongo otro par de antenas? Ambos edificios deben estar necesariamente en la misma red.

Muchas gracias por su atención, les deseo felices fiestas y el mejor año nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Más vale tarde que nunca...

Existe un standard para hacer lo que tu quieres. Al ser un standard, no es necesario que los switches sean del mismo proveedor, solo que sean administrables: Busca en los switches como configurar [LACP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation#Link_Aggregation_Control_Protocol), es algo bastante común en switches corporativos. Cisco le llama "EtherChannel", por ejemplo.

Considera que cada enlace es como el equivalente de un cable entre switches. Debes entonces configurar en ambos switches para que tome los dos puertos (uno por cada enlace de radio) que unen un switch con el otro como si fueran solo uno, lo que se llama *Port trunking* (o *link aggregation*, *link bundling*, *Ethernet/network/NIC bonding* o *NIC teaming*).

Espero te sirve aún.